# Turning a table on its side in MS Access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to turn a table on its side. I'm taking our massive database and counting the number of entries in each column to help find columns that could maybe be deleted or columns that should be shifted off into their own tables.  My query is giving me this data:

Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   etc
1       439   2       54

I want to turn this on it's side, so I have a table like so:

Name    Count
Col1    1
Col3    2
Col4    54
Col2    439

so I can easily sort the data in a meaningful way (there are a lot of columns, too many to make manual review plausible)

Anyone know some SQL that could

Comment: Possibly see `PIVOT`, although the example given still looks "right side up", just with more columns and a slightly different order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are trying to transpose the data (aka make the vertical horizontal and vice versa).

Here is the source from microsoft on how to do that : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202176